# form.on('submit') does not trigger after form.submit() but before

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit, onsubmit

I have a form onsubmit trigger and a confirm bootbox which shown on form submit button clicked. In bootbox confirm I submit form if user says yes. my problem is onsubmit triggers before user say yes and don't trigger again when I call `form.submit()` in bootbox.

```
<html>
  <form>
    <!-- something here -->
    <button type="submit"></button>
  </form>
</html>
<script>
form.on('submit', function(){
  //do something here (I)
}
form.validate({
  submitHandler: function (form) {
      finalConfirm(form); (II)
  }
});
function finalConfirm(form){
  confirm('message', function (confirmed) {
    if(confirmed) form.submit() (III)
  })
}
</script>
```

I expect `//do something here (I)` execute after `if(confirmed) form.submit() (III)` or at least both before and after, but it only execute before it (as I shown in code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `submit` **directly** on a `form` element (the DOM element, not a jQuery wrapper) does not trigger `submit` handlers. The argument that the validate plugin passes your `submitHandler` is the DOM element, not a jQuery wrapper for it (according to [this documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)).

Calling `submit` on a jQuery wrapper for a `form` element **does** trigger `submit` handlers (at least, the ones attached with jQuery). So if you want the `form.submit()` in `finalConfirm` to trigger your submit handler, create a jQuery wrapper for it:

```
$(form).submit();
```

(Either there, or before `submitHandler` passes it to `finalConfirm`.)

Just make sure you don't end up in an endless loop. :-)